# not work comandLink after use selectoneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, selectonemenu

I have a jsf page with code following :

```
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{calendar._year}" styleClass="cal_year form-control">
     <f:selectItems value="#{calendar._years}" var="year"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>      

 <p:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-success" value="search" 
                actionListener="#{date_custom.searchs}" action="index"
                update=":panel"/>
```

after using of selectOneMenu commandLink no work .

if remove selectOneMenu commandLink work right.

how to resolve my problem.

I have a bean class be binding to my jsf page :

```
 public class Calendar implements Serializable {

   private List<Integer> _years;
   private int _year = 2014;

   public List<Integer> get_years() {

    if (_years.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 2000; i < 2015; i++) {
            _years.add(i);
        }
    }


    return _years;
   }

   public void set_years(List<Integer> _years) {
    this._years = _years;
   }

   public int get_year() {
    return _year;
   }

   public void set_year(int _year) {
    this._year = _year;
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<i>    
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{calendar._years}" id="yearList">
        <f:selectItems value="#{calendar._years}" var="year"
                       itemLabel="#{year.name}" itemValue="#{year}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your f:selectItems seems incorrect - you haven't specified the items' values or labels.

Try

```
 <f:selectItems value="#{calendar._years}" var="year"
                   itemLabel="#{year}" itemValue="#{year}" />
```